# threshold data and compute odds ratio

Tags: r

I have a simple artificial data generation process:

```
n.site <- 150
X <- sort(runif(n = n.site, min = -1, max =1))
xb <- 0.0 + 3.0*X 
occ.prob <- 1/(1+exp(-xb))
plot(X, occ.prob,xlab="X",ylab="occ.prob")
Y <- rbinom(n = n.site, size = 1, prob = occ.prob)
plot(X, Y,xlab="X",ylab="Y")
```

I would like to bin X into intervals and compute the odds ratio (given Y). How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create bins, use the function `cut`:

```
dat <- data.frame(X, Y)
dat$bin <- cut(X, breaks=seq(-1, 1, 0.2))
```

Then use your favourite method to summarise. I illustrate `ddply` in package `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
Z <- ddply(dat, .(bin), summarize, yy = sum(Y)/length(Y))
```

Calculate the odds:

```
Z$odds <- Z$yy/(1-Z$yy)
```

Plot the results with base graphics...

```
plot(Z$bin, Z$odds)
```

[image]

... or `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Z, aes(x=bin, y=odds)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Where's that last (rightmost) point visible on the ggplot but not on the base graphics plot? It looks like ggplot is plotting 'Inf' values but base graphics is just giving a warning: Outlier (Inf) in boxplot 10 is not drawn